# Does the success of quantum teleportation means quantum cloning is possible too?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, quantum-teleportation

Well, I thought this might just be possible. Instead of having Bob and Alice having an entangled pair, they have multiple (> 2) amount of entangled quantum object (I'm not sure if this is possible too, but I assume it is because in quantum teleportation, when the measurement is taken B is simultaneously entangled with A and C). Alice has another qubit, which she proceeds to scan A and B together, and she gives the information to Bob, where he applies a suitable transformation to the rest of the quantum objects to the same qubit (C, D, E, F, G...)

Is this possible?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/77391/2451 and http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+cloning

Comment: The point is after quantum teleportation the original state will be destroyed.

Comment: 1)Qmechanic - Sorry but I don't quite understand those...

2)Ali - Well that shouldn't be a problem?

Comment: Clone implies having two of something, not just a copy and then destroy the original (teleportation)

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible due to unitarity of quantum mechanics; see the [no-cloning theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No-cloning_theorem).